# Is chess haram even if you're not intending to gamble?

Tags: halal-haram, game

I HEARD CHESS IS HARAM  but it seems ok if you want to have fun and not gamble

Comment: how does this even qualify as a good stackexchange question? no offense to the poster. this is more addressed to the admins/mods. i think this should be closed more as a unclear rather than a duplicate. i've noticed a lot of questions on islam se that are like this.

Answer (score 0):

Most scholars and Islamic schools say that playing chess is haram (Imam Malik, Ahmed, Abu Hanifa). However, there are few scholars who say it is OK to play chess if it does not distract you from doing compulsory things such as doing prayers at the right time or attending to your parents when they need you.

Comment: Chess being haram is most retarded thing I have heard. It's like other form of entertainments magically aren't like chess.

Comment: @Hegao disagree unless you count equally retarded that fortnite is haram while csgo isn't because fortnite has 'magic'. LOL https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/67176/i-play-a-game-called-fortnite-there-are-two-elements-in-it-shield-potion-and-ma p.s. i think it's politically incorrect to say 'retarded' unless you have some neurological disorder, neurodevelopmental disability or ADHD or autism or something

Comment: @BCLC Magic and sihr is literally two different things. Afaik shir means getting help from satans and its kinda illusions tricks. But magic is bending, changing laws or reality and things called mana to use magic. Which is completely fictional.

Comment: These 'fatwas' are historic. Whether they are still relevant or not is something for contemporary scholars to comment on. I think for historic 'fatwas' it is more important to focus on the rationale behind it, rather than the subject (chess). The rationale here is protecting people from being addictive to habits that are unproductive or distracting. Take computer games as an example. Many parents restrict screen time of their children, why? It is the same reason. My personal opinion is that video and computer games 'can' be by far much more harmful than chess.