# I play a game called Fortnite. There are two elements in it shield potion and magic carpet

Tags: game, sihr

In this game by drinking the shield potion your character gets some extra HP which works as a shield before your actual HP is starting to lose. And there is a magic carpet which works as a trampulin and makes you jump higher. I know that magic is haram. So, by using these items in this game also haram or it is Ok? Keep in mind that potions are magical substances like love potion etc

Comment: What about the magic carpet which makes you fly?

Answer (score 0):

Games are often places where people do what you must not do in reality.
Restrictive schools refuse reality-like games in general (haram)
Reality games where you do what in reality is forbidden are at least maqruh (not recommended).
"magic" elements like drinking love potion in theater or fiction is not a problem as long as nobody claims it to be reality.

Comment: Please consider supporting your claims by evidences.

Comment: I will try to assemble an overview over fatwas and publications on pictures, animation and related. There are different opinions on this topic.